# Bifurcation, classification and diagram

Tags: stability-in-odes, bifurcation

For the family of DEs $x'=(x^2-2x-\mu)(x-\mu),~x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\mu$ is a parameter. The questions asked to find the bifurcation points, classify them and draw the diagram. Of course finding the bifurcation is easy; by setting the RHS=0, which yields $x=1+\sqrt{1+ \mu}, 1-\sqrt{1+ \mu}$ and $x=\mu.$ Since $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ how can I go by and determine the two bifurcation points corresponding to the roots and answer other two questions. I'm sorry, I haven't come across bifurcation in my ODE classes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean look at the sign of the right hand side for values of $\mu$ smaller and greater to those three values ?

Comment: Can you draw three overlaying plots for the three critical points?

Answer (score 1):

The **equilibrium points** are found by setting the right side to $0$ and solving.  The **bifurcation points** are the values of $\mu$ where two or more solutions collide or start/finish being real.  Thus $\mu = -1$, $0$, $3$.
By examining what happens when $\mu$ is close to these values, you'll see that
$\mu = -1$ is a saddle-node bifurcation, where two equilibria appear on one side of the bifurcation but not on the other, while $\mu = 0$ and $\mu = 3$ are transcritical bifurcations, where two equilibria collide and exchange stability.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How did you come up with those three values for $\mu$ ?

Comment: The values of $\mu$ where two of the three equilibria coincide.  Thus $1 + \sqrt{1+\mu} = 1 - \sqrt{1+\mu}$ when $\mu = \ldots$.

Comment: I see. In general is there a criteria to determine the bifurcation points ? Or you do it by observation ?

Comment: For the DE $x' = f(x,\mu)$ where $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ for each $\mu$, you can take the discriminant with respect to $x$.  However, zeros of the discriminant might not always correspond to collisions of real roots.